# Ruby Mysql2 Client not taking backslash while insert

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

We are using production and staging databases in our application.
Our requirement is to insert all the records to staging database when ever a record is added in production database, so that both the servers are consistent and same data.

I have used Mysql2 client pool to connect to staging server and insert the record that is added to production.
 here is my code:

```
def create   
    @aperson = Person.new
    @person = @aperson.save
    if @person && Rails.env == "production"
      #add_new_person_to_staging

      client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => dbconfig[:host], :username => dbconfig[:username], :password => dbconfig[:password], :database => dbconfig[:database])        
      @person_result = client.query('INSERT INTO user_types(user_name,    regex, code) Values ("myname" , "\.myregex\." , "ns" );')
    end
end
```

Here "`@person_result`" record is inserted to mysql table but the "`regex`" column eliminates "\" slashes.

like :  `user_name = myname, regex = .myregex., code = ns`

when I manually execute the "Insert" query in mysql command line it inserts as it is along with \ slash. but not through "client.query" 
Why does `\ slash` is eliminated. please help me here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

\ is likely being removed by the MySQL2 client as part of a SQL injection protection preprocessor.

Have you looked at trying either a double backslash or using the [escape](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brianmario/mysql2/Mysql2/Client#escape-class_method) method to properly escape the string?

Comment: Yes I tried adding \\ slashes but both are eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this**

```
@person_result = client.query('INSERT INTO user_types(user_name, regex, code) Values (myname , "\."+myregx+".\" , ns )')
```

Comment: Its saving in mysql like this : 
  %#{myname}       %#{.myregex.}      %#{ns}